# How to add a modifier to a form id?

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

If I form alter a form, I see the form_id as `MY_FORM_ID`; I see this in the `$form_id` parameter to `hook_form_alter` as well as in the `$form_state->build_info['form_id']`. In the rendered output of the form, however, I see the id attribute has something like `MY-FORM-ID--2`, with a `--INT` modifier. If I output the same form twice on a page, while logged in the modifier is changed with each render (e.g. `MY-FORM-ID--2` and `MY-FORM-ID--4`), however the modifier is not changed when viewing as anon. This creates an instance where two elements have the same id attribute which is no good! :(

1. Where does core add the modifier?
2. How can I add a modifier?

Comment: Huh, I think we need to see the snippet how exactly you are outputting the form twice on a page...

Comment: I have a webform referenced on a node. The node is being rendered twice on the page.

Comment: As far as I know this modifier behavior is from core as I also see the same behavior with other, non webform, forms.

Comment: @sonfd, then you have to add a unique identifier to the form id when you instantiate the form class, in this case the most obvious would be the node id. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223269/cannot-deal-with-multiple-iterations-of-same-form-on-one-page