# Adding search form in header and home page creates SAME HTML ID validation issue

Tags: 8

I have added a search form in the header and content area of the home page from `block layout`. Forms are displayed fine and they are working well.

However, `w3.org` is flagging the HTML validation as having a duplicate ID.

The same thing is happening for my custom block which is added to the header and sidebar. I know I can remove `div ID` from custom block, but there must be a drupal way to fix this.

How do I avoid this?

**UPDATE**
Looks like drupal cache is to blame. When cache is turned off it generates forms with id like this: `id="search-block-form"` and `id="search-block-form--2"`. But as soon as I enable the cache it just generates like this: `id="search-block-form"` to all of them.

**WORKAROUND Solution**
I ended up loading the site after each cache clear in incognito mode or in a different browser as anonymous.

Comment: Solute to the expert who downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a similar question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272369/how-to-add-a-modifier-to-a-form-id) and there's another related question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223269/cannot-deal-with-multiple-iterations-of-same-form-on-one-page).

However, none of the solutions were particularly useful for me. In my case, this was a result of the form being cached too aggressively. I expect that's happening here too. For example, the form is first rendered in the header and the result is cached in the render cache. Then when the form is rendered the second time, e.g. in the main content region, the form is loaded from cache (rather than rebuilt) bypassing any core code to ensure a unique form id is generated.

Ultimately, you need to alter how the form's render result is cached so that each rendering rebuilds the form with a unique id. I found it difficult to generate unique cache information for the form without knowing the surrounding context so I used a workaround.

I implemented a [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) for the form in question and unset the cache keys property.  While this prevents the form object from being cached as its own object, the form is still cached as part of its parent container with all of the form's cache metadata bubbling up. I found this approach allows my form to render with unique ids with only a very small performance hit.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Ensure this form isn't cached as its own object, only with its parent.
  if (isset($form['#cache']['keys'])) {
    unset($form['#cache']['keys'];
  }
}
```

You can find more about [the cacheability of render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays) on d.o.

Answer (score -1):

Drupal core and its themes usually creates dynamic, unique IDs, so this should be coming from a custom module or theme. If you want to generate unique IDs in your own module/theme, you can use something like

```
<?php
$myUniqueButRandomId = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getUniqueId();
```

Docs:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AgetUniqueId/8.2.x